# Case insensitive match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match time string using REGEX.

```
([0-9]{1,2}:?(?:[0-9]{2})?)\s*?(AM?|PM?)
```

It currently matches all but lowercase.

> 02:03PM
>   02:03 AM
>   02:03 PM
>   2:03AM
>   2:03PM
>   2:03 AM
>   2:03 PM
>   02:03AM
>   02:03PM
>   02:03 A
>   02:03 P
>   2:03A
>   2:03P
>   2:03 A
>   2:03 P asdasd
>   a6:00 PMsa
>   02:03PM
>   02:03 A
>   02:03 P
>   2:03A
>   2:03P
>   2:03 A
>   2:03 P asdasd
>   2:03 am
>   2:03 pm
>   02:03aM
>   02:03pM
>   02:03 aA
>   02:03 p
>   2:03a

How do I fix this? adding /i seems to break the whole expression.

Comment: Which context? Sed, awk, egrep, perl, java, python, ...?

Comment: I use it in PHP.